# How to change file extension handling on PHP's built-in server?

Tags: php

My project uses `html` for file extensions and we handle that on apache to be handled the same as `php` ones.

But for development I want to use PHP's built-in server: `php -S`

I can pass a config file to it (`php -S ... -c my_conf.ini`) but I can't find any way to force it to handle `html` extensions as php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not test, but worth a shot:

Use a `.htaccess`

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html
```

**Edit** Another option to try:

start the server like this `php -S ... <router.php>`

In `router.php` try to include the `.html` files. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on SirPilan's answer, here's what I used to handle PHP tags in `.html` files:

```php
<?php
// ../dev-router.php
if (preg_match('/\.(php|html)$/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {
  include(__DIR__ . '/public_html' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
  return;
}

// Default: serve the requested resource as-is.
return false;
```

Then, to run it:

```bash
cd public_html
php -S localhost:8080 ../dev-router.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a issue when trying to start the server with

```
sudo php -S localhost:80
```

But without passing the PHP extension I'm not able to see these files.
This is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\. - [H=application/x-httpd-php]
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32684064)